Rolling Sum with Max condition in SQL
I'm trying to achieve a rolling sum with a max condition. Basically trying to do a rolling sum but before we roll the 1st row sum to the next row we have to check with a condition if the rolling value is less than or equal to Zero. If it is less than zero we have to make it as zero else we will roll the sum with the +ve value. Please see sample below (3rd row - i'm getting -5 so the rolling sum should set to 0).
Stock_left = Stock + PO - Fcst
NOTE: (Stock is only at 1st row, from next row stock will be Stock_left of previous row)



Date
Item Code
Warehouse
Stock
PO
Fcst
Stock_left




7/8/2024
1343411
000
50
0
5
45


7/9/2024
1343411
000
45
0
20
25


7/10/2024
1343411
000
25
0
30
-5


7/11/2024
1343411
000
0
10
5
5




--> Check if 45<0, if yes, take 0 for next Stock
--> Check if 25<0, if yes, take 0 for next Stock
--> Check if -5<0, if yes, take 0 for next Stock
--> Check if 15<0, if yes, take 0 for next Stock
enter image description here


tag the sql dialect that you are using. Don't spam text to bypass the word limit. Show your current attempt.

Use a greatest() function.  If your SQL dialect does not have it then code it as a CASE WHEN.

I'm confused about which columns are actually in the input data and which are calculated. Is this not just a case of CASE WHEN LAG(Stock + PO - Fcst) OVER (ORDER BY Date) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Stock End?

If we assume SQL-Server then we can apply your data to this example how to reset cumulative sum when reached to threshold
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by Date) as seqnum
      from inventory t
     ),
     cte as (
      select seqnum, Date, t.stock_left, t.stock_left as NextStock
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.seqnum, t.Date, t.stock_left,
             (case when t.stock_left < 0 then 0
                   else cte.NextStock + t.stock_left
              end) 
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;

fiddle



seqnum
Date
stock_left
NextStock




1
2024-07-08
45
45


2
2024-07-09
25
70


3
2024-07-10
-5
0


4
2024-07-11
15
15




Hi, Thanks for your response. Next stock is not supposed to be rolling. Stock Left is already calculated based on previous value. When we hit stock left < 0 then we have to set it to 0 and start the further rolling sum with this 0 value. you have to calculate Stock and then use it in next row for stock_left formula.

@Nikhil CR  I do not understand. Please provide a table with the expected output.

So basically, when you calculate Stock_Left fors 1st row using the formula (Stock + PO - Fcst), It should go to the stock for the next day. If negative, we say stock on next day is 0 and perform the rolling sum further. See screenshot. I just updated for above post.
